# Error in using map function for generating spectogram through 'Librosa' in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, librosa

I'm trying to convert tf data to a spectrogram using librosa which I would then feed to a Tensorflow CNN for an Audio Classification problem. I keep getting a 'Positional Argument' error that I have also replicated below.

```
### the shape of the data that I'm trying to process
train
# <TakeDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>

### a single instance of the dataset
train.as_numpy_iterator().next()
# (b'/content/drive/MyDrive/data/True/A8-T.wav', 1.0)

### Function to take return a spectogram
def preprocess(file_path, label): 

   spectrogram = mel_spec(file_path)

   spectrogram = tf.expand_dims(spectrogram, axis=2)
   return spectrogram, label

### mel spectogram beig called in the previous function
def mel_spec(af):
   y , sr = librosa.load(af)
   S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y,
                                sr=sr,
                                n_mels= 128 * 2,)
   mel_spectogram = librosa.amplitude_to_db(S, ref=np.max)
   return mel_spectogram

### Using map function to run the code
```

[image: Error using map]

Using the function separately gives the expected result

```
spm , lbl = preprocess(train.as_numpy_iterator().next())
spm.shape , lbl
```

[image]

I'm not sure why the positional argument keeps popping up even though I specifically have a single argument there. How can I address this?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you show, the function you are trying to use map on, has two positional arguments.

```
def preprocess(file_path, label):
   ...
```

It must have a single positional argument.